# Playing a sound when the object gets through a specific rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play a sound whenever the object rotates through a certain point. The code was working fine, but then it suddenly stopped and I don't know what else to do.

The object is a door and according to Unity's transform information, it's rotating along its Z-axis from -180 through -300. I want the sound "portaFechando" to play when the door transform.rotation.z is less than -190, but it's not working.

I can just hear the "portaAbrindo" sound.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class abrirPorta : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    bool portaFechada = true;
    public AudioSource audio;
    public AudioClip abrindo;
    public AudioClip fechando;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        // checkando input para abrir a porta
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && portaFechada == true)
        {
            anim.SetBool("portaFechada", false);
            anim.SetFloat("portaSpeed", 1);
            portaFechada = false;
            audio.clip = abrindo;
            audio.Play();

        }

        // checkando input para fechar porta
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && portaFechada == false)
        {
            anim.SetBool("portaFechada", true);
            anim.SetFloat("portaSpeed", -1);
            portaFechada = true;
         }

        // tocando som de fechando checkando rotação (bugou)
        if (portafechada == false && transform.rotation.z <= -190)
        {
            Debug.Log("Worked!");
            audio.clip = fechando;
            audio.Play();

        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're accessing the z component of a quaternion, which is not a measure of angles around the z axis.

Instead, refer to `transform.eulerAngles.z`, which will be a value between 0 and 360. Here, -190 is equivalent to 170 and -300 is equivalent to 60 so, you can check if `transform.eulerAngles.z` is less or equal to 170.

I would also recommend keeping track of if the closing sound has already played since the door closing button has been pressed. Also, instead of only playing the sound when `portafechada` is false, you want to only play it when it's true:

```
Animator anim;
bool portaFechada = true;
public AudioSource audio;
public AudioClip abrindo;
public AudioClip fechando;

private bool playedSoundAlready = true;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // checkando input para abrir a porta
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && portaFechada)
    {
        anim.SetBool("portaFechada", false);
        anim.SetFloat("portaSpeed", 1);
        portaFechada = false;
        audio.clip = abrindo;
        audio.Play();
    }

    // checkando input para fechar porta
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && !portaFechada)
    {
        anim.SetBool("portaFechada", true);
        anim.SetFloat("portaSpeed", -1);
        portaFechada = true;
        playedSoundAlready = false;
     }

    // tocando som de fechando checkando rotação (bugou)
    if (!playedSoundAlready && portaFechada && transform.eulerAngles.z <= 170)
    {
        playedSoundAlready = true;
        Debug.Log("Worked!");
        audio.clip = fechando;
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd tried your solution, but now it just plays the "fechando" sound. The "abrindo" is not playing anymore.

Comment: @GuiVasconcelos I read the wrong angle when I was copying and pasting things. Try how it is in the answer now.

Comment: @GuiVasconcelos I added a bit to check if the closing sound is already playing because it seems like you don't already check for that.

Comment: Thank you, but it still not working. I still just hear the "fechando" not the "abrindo" anymore. 

If i remove the ! from portafechada, the abrindo sound plays. It's a logical conflict ithink.

Comment: @GuiVasconcelos try that. I was checking for the wrong value of `portaFechada`. I also changed how to check if the closing sound was already played. Let me know if that works